# How to transfer multiple files to different directories at the same time

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have created a file transfer service using wso2 integration studio. This service works with a file connector. I have it working from one directory to another, however I want to change this method to work with multiple directories. Initially, I had 2 sequences and a task to do this process, namely, "  "FileListenerSeq" sequence, "FileReadSeq" sequence and "FileTask" scheduled task.

I have now created 2 extra sequences and a new task to do the same process. Namely, "FileReplyListenerSeq" sequence, "FileReplyReadSeq" sequence and "ReplyTask" scheduled task.

I want these sequences to work at the same time but even after creating the new sequences and task, the micro-integrator only reads the first initial process. I tried adding the same process twice in one sequence and it works but works only after the first one is done (which makes sense)

Is there a way to do this concurrently with multiple sequences that work at the same time?

environment specs:

- Integration studio :  8.1.0
- wso2 micro integrator : 7.1.0
- file connector : 4.0.11

process flow from directory to directory:

- LOCATION 1: FOLDERA  --> LOCATION 2: FOLDERB  ( This is the process that was created initially and works)
- LOCATION 1: FOLDERC -->  LOCATION 2: FOLDERD ( This is the new process I want to work with the initial process)

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

FileReadSeq source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="FileReadSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property description="file name" expression="//file/text()" name="FILE_TO_READ" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:FILE_TO_READ" name="Files to read"/>
    </log>
    <file.read configKey="LocalFolderAConnection">
        <path>{fn:concat('/OUTGOING/' , $ctx:FILE_TO_READ)}</path>
        <readMode>Complete File</readMode>
        <startLineNum>0</startLineNum>
        <endLineNum>0</endLineNum>
        <lineNum>0</lineNum>
        <contentType>application/binary</contentType>
        <includeResultTo>Message Body</includeResultTo>
        <enableStreaming>true</enableStreaming>
        <enableLock>false</enableLock>
    </file.read>
    <file.write configKey="LocalFolderBConnection">
        <filePath>{$ctx:FILE_PATH}</filePath>
        <mimeType>Automatic</mimeType>
        <compress>false</compress>
        <writeMode>Overwrite</writeMode>
        <enableStreaming>true</enableStreaming>
        <appendNewLine>false</appendNewLine>
        <enableLock>false</enableLock>
        <includeResultTo>Message Body</includeResultTo>
        <updateLastModified>true</updateLastModified>
    </file.write>
    <file.read configKey="LocalFolderCConnection">
        <path>{fn:concat('/Incoming/' , $ctx:FILE_TO_READ)}</path>
        <readMode>Complete File</readMode>
        <startLineNum>0</startLineNum>
        <endLineNum>0</endLineNum>
        <lineNum>0</lineNum>
        <contentType>application/binary</contentType>
        <includeResultTo>Message Body</includeResultTo>
        <enableStreaming>true</enableStreaming>
        <enableLock>false</enableLock>
    </file.read>
    <file.write configKey="LocalFolderDConnection">
        <filePath>{$ctx:FILE_PATH}</filePath>
        <mimeType>Automatic</mimeType>
        <compress>false</compress>
        <writeMode>Overwrite</writeMode>
        <enableStreaming>true</enableStreaming>
        <appendNewLine>false</appendNewLine>
        <enableLock>false</enableLock>
        <includeResultTo>Message Body</includeResultTo>
        <updateLastModified>true</updateLastModified>
    </file.write>
    <filter regex="true" source="//writeResult/success/text()">
        <then>
            <log description="Status Log " level="custom">
                <property expression="$ctx:FILE_TO_READ" name="files successfully moved"/>
            </log>
        </then>
        <else>
            <log description="Failed log">
                <property name="message" value="Files failed to move"/>
            </log>
        </else>
    </filter>
</sequence>
```

Comment: As long as you are pointing to two separate directories there shouldn't be any interference. Can you share your FileRead sequences?

Comment: Hi, Yes its pointing to different directories. If you see the process flow above, you can see that it transfers from folderA to folderB and then I want the same process to happen from folderC to folderD.

Comment: I have added the source code above

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for the requirement would be to use file inbound endpoints[1]. You can create multiple inbound endpoints for each file location from where you need to process files. The inbound endpoint will be listening to the defined `transport.vfs.FileURI` location and the files will be processed parallelly from multiple inbound endpoints. Since the requirement is to transfer the files, you can set the `transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess` parameter to `MOVE` and set the destination file location using the `transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess` parameter.

Please refer to the documentation here[1] for more details.

[1] https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/inbound_endpoint_examples/file-inbound-endpoint/